# How does SoftICE stop the windows system?

Tags: softice

Please help!

How does SoftICE stop the windows system? Is it hooks IDT ? 
I'm trying use that feature on my hobby driver. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, just from curiosity. Is SoftICE still around? Or is it just an old question. I remember using it back in the 90's.

Answer (score 2):

SoftICE hooks multiple entries in the IDT for its purposes.  This is visible if you execute SIDT directly.  However, if you ask for the IDT from within the SoftICE UI, you'll see the original value instead.